# How to Import a Custom Evaluation to my VertexAI Model

Tags: google-cloud-platform, classification, confusion-matrix, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have a classification model, and I want to import an evaluation model instance into the graphical interface of VertexAI using this code:

```
from google.cloud.aiplatform import gapic
metrics = {"auPrc": 0.92}
metrics["auRoc"] = 0.93
metrics["auRoc"] = 0.93
metrics["logLoss"] = 0.26
metrics["logLoss"] = 0.26
metrics["confidenceMetrics"] = [{"confidenceThreshold": -0.005,
                                 "confusionMatrix": {
                                     "annotationSpecs": [{"displayName": "less", "id": "0"}, {"displayName": "more", "id": "1"}],
                                     "rows": [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
                                 },
                                 "f1Score": 0.66,
                                 "f1ScoreAt1": 0.66,
                                 "falsePositiveCount": "3000",
                                 "falsePositiveRate": "1",
                                 "falsePositiveRateAt1": 1,
                                 "precision":  d["evaluationReport"]["predictorsPerformance"][0]["accuracy"],
                                 "precisionAt1": 0.5,
                                 "recall": 1,
                                 "recallAt1": 1,
                                 "truePositiveCount": "3000"
                                }
                               ]

model_eval = gapic.ModelEvaluation(
    display_name="eval",
    metrics_schema_uri="gs://google-cloud-aiplatform/schema/modelevaluation/classification_metrics_1.0.0.yaml",
    metrics=metrics,
)
API_ENDPOINT = f"{REGION}-aiplatform.googleapis.com"
client = gapic.ModelServiceClient(client_options={"api_endpoint": API_ENDPOINT})
client.import_model_evaluation(parent=my_model.resource_name, model_evaluation=model_eval)
```

I can achieve this successfully when I don't use the information about confusionMatrix key. However, when I include it, I encounter this error: `InternalServerError: 500 Internal error encountered` .
Could you please help me with this issue?